# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn save SelectedText for each row in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

This is `T-SQL` for Inserting data from `datagridview` into `SQL Table` but the issue is that one of datagridview's column is `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`and I need for each row save particular selected item in combobox. May I ask how it can be done?

```
    public DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbColumn;
conn.Open();
        SqlTransaction sqlTrans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {

            string delCmdTxt = "DELETE FROM PRONAJEM WHERE NA_CISLKU=@NA_CISLKU";
            SqlCommand cmdDel = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmdDel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NA_CISLKU",VybraneCisku);
            cmdDel.CommandText = delCmdTxt;
            cmdDel.Transaction = sqlTrans;
            cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string insert_sql = "INSERT INTO PRONAJEM(DATUM,PLODINA,CENAMJ,MNOZSTVIMJ,PRIKAZ,NA_ZUSTA,NA_CISLKU,RODNECISLO)VALUES" +
                "(@DATUM,@PLODINA,@CENAMJ,@MNOZSTVIMJ,@PRIKAZ,@NA_ZUSTA,@NA_CISLKU,@RODNECISLO)";
            using (SqlCommand sqlcom = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlcom.CommandText = insert_sql;
                sqlcom.Transaction = sqlTrans;

                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@DATUM", SqlDbType.Date); //Replace with whatever the correct datatypes are
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@PLODINA", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@CENAMJ", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@MNOZSTVIMJ", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@PRIKAZ", SqlDbType.Date);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@NA_ZUSTA", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@NA_CISLKU", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@RODNECISLO", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                var validRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(row => row.Cells["DATUM"].Value != null);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in validRows)
                {
                    sqlcom.Parameters[0].Value = row.Cells["DATUM"].Value;
                    sqlcom.Parameters[1].Value = row.Cells["POLOZKAcb"].Value;
                    sqlcom.Parameters[2].Value = row.Cells["CENAMJ"].Value;
                    sqlcom.Parameters[3].Value = row.Cells["MNOZSTVIMJ"].Value;
                    sqlcom.Parameters[4].Value = row.Cells["PRIKAZ"].Value;
                    sqlcom.Parameters[5].Value = row.Cells["NA_ZUSTA"].Value;
                    sqlcom.Parameters[6].Value = VybraneCisku;
                    sqlcom.Parameters[7].Value = VybraneRodneCislo;

                    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                sqlcom.Dispose();
            }
            sqlTrans.Commit();
```

This is the creating of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn:

```
 string query = "SELECT * FROM PLODINY ";
            SqlCommand newcom = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader= newcom .ExecuteReader();

            List<string> listPlodiny = new List<string>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                listPlodiny.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PLODINA")) + "-" + Decimal.Parse(reader["CENAZAQ"].ToString()).ToString());
                for (int i = 0; i <= listPlodiny.Count() - 1; i++)
                {

                }
            }
            cbColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cbColumn.DataSource = listPlodiny;
            cbColumn.DropDownWidth = 100;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cbColumn);
            cbColumn.DisplayIndex = 3;
            cbColumn.HeaderText = "Položka";
            cbColumn.DataPropertyName = "POLOZKAcb";
```

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because you not set a `.ValueMember` property for `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`...
You need to set
    `.ValueMember` - set Value for Cell from DataSource's property.
        This value will be referenced with Column.DataPropertyName's value.
    `.DisplayMember`- Value of this will be used for diplay text in dropdown cell

Try next(updated for using of `DataTable` as `DataSource` in `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`:

```
DataTable dtPlodiny;
using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn))//conn - your connection string
{
    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT ID, Description FROM PLODINY"; //better practice use only fields you need
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dtPlodiny);
    }
}
cbColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cbColumn.Name = "POLOZKAcb" 
cbColumn.DataSource = dtPlodiny; //Changed with DataTable

//add next two rows
cbColumn.DisplayMember = "Description" //property from .Datasource you want to show for user
cbColumn.ValueMember = "ID" //property from .Datasource you want use as Value - reference to DataPropertyName

cbColumn.DropDownWidth = 100;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cbColumn);
cbColumn.DisplayIndex = 3;
cbColumn.HeaderText = "Položka";
cbColumn.DataPropertyName = "POLOZKAcb";
```

If your datagridview use always same columns,
then I think easally if you use a predefined columns(created/added through Designer).   Then you can set a name for every column and use it in code as object:
`this.MyColumnPolozka.Name...`
for example...

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I get this Ex.:Child list for filed PLODINY cannot be created.

Comment: This is because your `DataSource` of column haven't `Description` property... If you popup dropdown with database values, then maybe better using `DataTable`..., will update answer for DataTable

Comment: Thank you. Now it displayes the data. May I know how then Selected Values save into SQL DB? Now I get ex: Additional information Column named POLOZKAcb cannot be found. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to set a `.Name` property for your comboboxcolumn , updated a answer with this line....

Comment: Thank you for your help, everything worked well. I have created another question as I'm bit stuck with this ComboBoxColumn issue it is about SelectingText in this ComboBoxColumn - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933955/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-load-from-sql-as-selectedtext-in-each-row

Answer (score 1):

if you donot get correct value from `row.Cells(0).Value` then try casting it to dropdownlist

Comment: Thank you for your comment. From row.Cells(0).Value I have received null even thought there was selected text. May I know how it can be casted to dropdownlist?