# Select Item in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn loaded from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

This is `SqlDataAdapter` that I use for filling `dataGridView1` but before I fill it I add `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to that datagridview So I will be able to select item in ComboboxColumn that is stored in SQL. But I'm not sure how it can be achieved.

```
 dtSelectPronajem = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PRONAJEM WHERE NA_CISLKU=@NA_CISLKU", conn);
            SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NA_CISLKU", VybraneCisku);
            SDA.Fill(dtSelectPronajem);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtSelectPronajem;
```

Creating DataGridViewComboBoxColumn:

```
private void EditDGV()
    {
        try
        {

            DataTable dtPlodiny = new DataTable();
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT PLODINA, CENAZAQ FROM PLODINY"; 
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dtPlodiny);
                }

                cbColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                cbColumn.DataSource = dtPlodiny; //Changed with DataTable

                //add next two rows
                cbColumn.DisplayMember = "PLODINA";
                cbColumn.ValueMember = "PLODINA"; //property from .Datasource you want use as Value - reference to DataPropertyName

                cbColumn.DropDownWidth = 100;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cbColumn);
                cbColumn.HeaderText = "Položka";
                this.cbColumn.Name = "POLOZKAcb";

        }
```

My question is - how is possible to SelectText in ComboBox for each row that is loaded from  SQL? The value that should be then selected as SelectedText in ComboBox is in SQL column named `PLODINA`.

Thank for your time so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataGridViewColumn` must be added to `DataGridView` before you set `.DataSource`.

Then set `.DataPropertyName` for new column:

```
cbColumn.DataPropertyName = "PLODINA"
```

`DataPropertyName` must be name of the field from "PRONAJEM" table.
And then item of comboboxcolumn where `.ValueMember = PRONAJEM.PLODINA(from DataTable)` will be selected